# MySQL not working on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: mysql

I run the **mysql** command at the command line but I get this error:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I've Googled a lot but I'm unable to resolve the issue.

Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like mysql isn't running. This will tell you if it is or not:

```
 sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the path you specified doesnt have the socket required to connnect to the mysql. This problem has happened with me. Either you can reinstall mysql or search for the mysqld.sock and then move it to the specified directory.

Try running this command to start the mysql server

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start 
 /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: I ran the commands you gave, but I get the following message:
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.56" (uid=1000 pid=7531 comm="start mysql ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init"))